# Posting Supergroup Messages with Python-Telegram-Bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have been sending Telegram messages to a chat using the code below. It worked fine but the group has been upgraded to a "Supergoup" and it has stopped working. It just gives a "Chat cannot be found" error.

I have the new ID and found a suggestion that I needed to add the bot as admin for the group. Neither of these has fixed the problem.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
bot = telegram.Bot(token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

def post(message):
    msg = dedent(f'''\
        On subject {subject}: {message}
        ''')
    bot.send_message('-1111111111', text=msg)
```

Comment: double check that you are passing the correct new `chat_id`. it should start with a `-100` for supergroups

Comment: Thanks @CallMeStag it's correct though